# Constrain a Specman list so it doesn't have identical values in consecutive elements

Tags: constraints, specman, e

I want to generate list in Specman from a limited range and ensure that no two consecutive entries in the list have the same value so these would be OK

```
[1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
[2,1,3,1,3,2,1]
[100, 22, 50, 62, 100]
```

but these would not

```
[1,0,1,1,1,0,1]
[2,3,3,1,3,2,1]
[100, 22, 50, 50, 100]
```

I've tried to use unique() like so

```
mylist[mylist_len] : list of uint;
keep mylist.unique(it).size() == mylist.size()
```

and I can't just keep it using a scalar either

```
keep mylist.unique(it).size() == mylist_len
```

I also tried using keep on the entries like so

```
keep for each (i) in mylist {
  if (index > 0) {
    keep mylist[index] != mylist[index+1];
  };
};
```

It it matters I'm constraining the entries in the list like so:

```
keep for each (i) in mylist {
    i < mylist_limit;
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use 'prev' in a 'for each'.

```
keep for each (i) in mylist {
    i < mylist_limit;
    i != prev;
};
```